# How to pass access Token via API URL - Laravel Passport

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5.4, access-token, laravel-passport

I use Passport package for API Authentication in Laravel Project.

I pass access token via header to verify User actions. but, i need to send access token via API URL.

Like this :

http://aarts.net/rest/api/v1/cart?access_token=vIRTPypU16SuMar6xSK1clzGXOGvOwQPX3WoT71A

[image]

I need to send access token via API URL.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but I can hardly understand your question, could you explain it better?

Comment: can you show your code? where you pass the access token via header?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry,you can't do that, laravel passport does not support